# RingCentral MMS image public URI

Tags: node.js, ringcentral

Images sent as MMS messages are accessible via the RingCentral API message store endpoint:

`https://media.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/message-store/~/content/`

Can these attachment URIs be made publicly available so as to access them in a different application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, the image URIs require authorization with a valid RingCentral access token with permissions to those resources.

Opening these up for access without authorization would be a feature request. To request this, please email me at the address in my profile or join the RingCentral developer chat at https://glipped.herokuapp.com.